# google map incorrect UI display, also the map is displaced of some offset

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-maps

I am trying to display a google map inside a div, which is in an outer div that is hidden at first. When the outer div is toggled shown, the initialization of the map is triggered. In the initialization function, "google.maps.event.trigger(gMap, 'resize');" is used.

I'm a new registered user, and cannot post any image, so here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Pd72p/

HTML:

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="opt">
        <div class="bar">
            &#x25bc Info1
        </div>
        <div class="description">
            <p>Info1</p>
            <div class="bttn">Learn more</div>
        </div>
        <div class="bar">
            &#x25bc Info2
        </div>
        <div class="description">
            <p>Info2</p>
            <div id="map"></div>
            <div class="bttn">Learn more</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hidden{
display:none;
}

#opt{
margin:0;
padding:0;
/*width:80%;*/
}
#opt div{
margin:2%;
padding:1%;
width:96%;
}
#opt .bar{
background-color:#ffc933;
}
#opt .bar:hover, #opt .description .bttn:hover{
background-color:#55ee55;
cursor:pointer;
}
#opt .description{
border-top:dotted;
border-bottom:dotted;
}

#opt .description .bttn{
margin:20px 0px 0px 0px;
padding:10px;
width:100px;
background-color:#ffa822;
text-align:center;
border-radius:5px;
}

#map{
width:200px;
height:200px;
}
```

JS:

```
"use strict";

$(function(){
    $('#opt .description').addClass('hidden');
    $('#opt .bar').click(function(){
        $(this).next().slideToggle();
        if ($('#map').is(':visible'))
        {
            initializeMap();
        }
    });
});


function initializeMap() {

    // default location
    var initialLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(33.4500, -112.0667);

    var mapOptions = {
        center: initialLatLng,
        zoom: 13,
        //disableDefaultUI: true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
    };
    var gMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

    var gMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: initialLatLng,
        map: gMap});

    google.maps.event.trigger(gMap, 'resize');
}
//google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initializeMap);
```

The div directly containing the map has both width and height set to 500px (in the fiddle I set it to 200px). So first, it should be a square. But now it is a rectangle. Changing the css only changes the height but the width is always displayed the same.

Secondly, the top left corner is displaced by some positive offset to the right and bottom.

Third, the UI controls are not displayed correctly. They are a mess, and also causes problem when I try to drag the map. If I use disableDefaultUI:true, the issue with dragging goes away.

So I want to see if any body can help me with getting it work.

Thanks!

Comment: while you can't post images, you can definitely post code, and link to a http://jsfiddle.net/ with your relevant tries

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Just updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It think the css

```
#opt div{
  margin:2%;
  padding:1%;
  width:96%;
}
```

it's applying to some map elements, you can use

```
#opt > div{
  margin:2%;
  padding:1%;
  width:96%;
}
```

or put a class to the div you want to change